# How to add two react-select on one page using functional base

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm a bit confused, here's an example with a multiple selected inputs that have with the error.

- How can I make it so when I select an option the value does not apply to the rest of the select inputs?
- How would you put the values in the store for each of the selects?
- Do I need multiple stores?

For more clarity, here is a screenshot:
[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpo2x.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You cannot declare two constants (variables, functions, classes) with the same name. Regarding the rest of the question, I cannot make heads or tails of what you're asking.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to implement two multiple selects in one react file.